# Download pull request that hasn't been accepted

Tags: android-studio, github

I need to download the following pull request because the main library has some issues and it's not getting updated: https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable/pull/33

Is it possible to download this pull request and use it as a library in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the commits tab and click the button that looks like <> by the commit you want. Then click the download zip file (assuming you meant download, and not checkout).